# Has Many Through Relationship in MongoDB with ONE query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, activerecord

I want to create the following two pages, using ONE query each:

1. A list of all courses for a particular student
2. A list of all students for a particular course

I would like the recreate the following with MongoDB (or another NoSQL solution)

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :courses, :through=>:assignments
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :students, :through=>:assignments
end

class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :student
```

With a relational database, I can accomplish this by eager loading the association.

However in Mongo, when I create by schema, I can either chose to embed or link the student data in the course, or embed or link the course data in the student.

If I chose to embed the student data in the course document, I can easily pull all students for a particular course (one document).  However, if I want to find all courses a particular student is taking, I will have to query MongoDB N times (where N is the number of courses a student is taking)!

In a web application backed by a relational database, making N calls to the database to load a page isn't an option.  It needs to be done in a constant number of queries.  Is this not the case with MongoDB?  Is there a way to structure my documents such that I can load the two pages above with ONE query?

Answer (score 0):

```
 If I chose to embed the student data in the course document, I
 can easily pull all students for a particular course (one document).
 However, if I want to find all courses a particular student is taking,
 I will have to query MongoDB N times (where N is the number of courses
 a student is taking)!
```

If you keep your information highly normalized, that is correct.  There are other possibilities, though, such as maintaining an array of current course IDs in the student record rather than relying on relationship queries.

```
 In a web application backed by a relational database, making N calls
 to the database to load a page isn't an option. It needs to be done
 in a constant number of queries. Is this not the case with MongoDB?
 Is there a way to structure my documents such that I can load the two
 pages above with ONE query?
```

MongoDB is not a relational database, and intentionally does not support joins.  The MongoDB data modelling approach is more akin to a data warehouse, where some data is denormalized or embedded in related data to remove the need for joins.

There is a client driver notion of relationships using the convention of [Database References (DBRefs)](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/database-references/) but there is no server support for hydrating references and these will result in additional queries.

Multiple queries aren't necessarily *bad* .. but the general design goal would be to model your data to most effectively balance speed of inserts, updates, and reads based on your application's common use cases.

For more information on data modelling, see:

- [MongoDB Schema Design](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design) .. includes some best practices and related links
- [Designing MongoDB Schemas with Embedded, Non-Embedded and Bucket Structures](https://openshift.redhat.com/community/blogs/designing-mongodb-schemas-with-embedded-non-embedded-and-bucket-structures)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I understand that MongoDB doesn't support joins, but in a web application, having over about 20 DB queries to load a page is not an acceptable solution, and it appears if I have the two use cases described above, it would be impossible to have both of the use cases satisfied without at least one loading 20 or more docs.  If my goal is to optimize reads only, this can't be done without denormalizing the data, which the Schema Design document you link to suggests against!  I didn't know if NoSQL solutions had a strategy to combat this, or if relational DBs win here.